# Self-Transitions is possible in activiti

Tags: workflow, activiti

I am using Activiti Engine as workflow engine.
There is any way to do Self-Transition in activiti?
as this is available in JBPM workflow engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use executionlistener for implementing task transition.

```
    public class MyExecution_Transition_Listener  implements ExecutionListener{

      @Override  public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception { 
      //write logic here
}
 }
```

Comment: One more way to this by adding one extra node.